# How deep would a Roman Marian cohort's battle line be, in a melee?

Tags: military, roman-republic, tactics, ancient-rome, combat

Are there any estimates for how deep a Roman battle line was, under Marius, at the level of a cohort? Whether the line was 3, 6, or another number of ranks deep?

I'd suppose 3 would be a minimum, and something like 4 would be more standard?

I would settle for estimates for a pre-Marian Roman line.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Found what looks to be a related, if not identical question here: [What did the battle order of a deployed Roman legion look like?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/54408/what-did-the-battle-order-of-a-deployed-roman-legion-look-like) . Does that answer your question? Admittedly, it appears that by our only objective measure (votes), the answer below has to be considered better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody knows.

Historians debate this, as what surviving Latin documents we have are either ambiguous; or presuppose knowledge which has been lost over time; or both.

Beyond the broad layout as (depending on period) cohorts, maniples, and centuries, in lines of hastati, principes and triarii in the earlier period, we know little beyond [Caesar choosing to "*thin*" his line at Pharsalus](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Caesar/Civil_Wars/3D*.html) to avoid being overlapped.

> At the same time, having noticed the arrangements mentioned above, fearing lest his right wing should be surrounded by the multitude of cavalry, [Caesar] hastily withdrew individual cohorts from the third line and out of these constructed a fourth line, stationing it opposite the cavalry, explaining what his object was and reminding them that the day's victory depended on the valour of these cohorts.

Reading this, it's even unclear to me how "*from the third line*" should be interpreted. The preceding but one sentence has just described **three wings** in left, right, and centre, and he now describes the *ad hoc* formation of what is clearly a *fourth wing*, refused on his right to counter Pompeius' cavalry opposite. The next sentence muddies further, rather than clarifying:

> At the same time he commanded the third line and the whole army not to join battle without orders from himself, saying that when he wished this to be done he would give the signal with a flag.

Why is the *third line* being emphasized here? Perhaps the original Latin helps - but more likely, to me, is that the translator has attempted to interpret as best possible. The constant, apparent at least, conflation of *wings* with *lines* clearly presupposes basic understanding of terminology and practice lost to time.